# How to modify SimpleAdapter (Android) source code?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, simpleadapter

I'm developing an Android app which uses Google Places Autocomplete to search for text typed in an `autocompletetextview`. It works perfectly only when one parameter is entered.

eg. if I type 'pizza', I get location biased dropdown results starting with the word 'pizza'. But if I type 'pizza hut', the dropdown list vanishes when I press the space button.

I want to modify the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java/) of `SimpleAdapter` to make a slightly modified `CustomSimpleAdapter` to populate the `autocompletetextview`. I need the exact same constructor used in `SimpleAdapter` with filtering to include white space.

Comment: If you modify AOSP sources you need to build Android with those modifications merged, which is not a viable solution for most app developers. Instead, you can write your own adapter.

Comment: Maybe you can use AutoCompleteTextView instead of edit Text and get the list of suggestions in an async way ...

Comment: @Zygote I dont want to directly modify the AOSP sources. i was thinking to copy the code in new java file & make the necessary changes to suit my needs.

Comment: @RalucaGurau i already use an autocompletetextview. Wrote textview by mistake.